# Can I continue use my VMware Workstation virtual machine before a snapshot completed?

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware, vmware-workstation, snapshot

I'm using VMware Workstation on Windows. When I create a snapshot while my guest VM is running, it will take long time (probably more than 10 minutes) to complete the whole process. During this period, you can see the completion percentage of the snapshot at the bottom left corner of the window.

[image]

I can still operate normally in the VM wile the snapshot is in progress. Should I stop doing anything in the VM and wait until it completes? A similar situation happens when you restore a snapshot.

Answer (score 0):

VMware takes the snapshot and you can use the VM if you need to, but anything you do past this point will not be in the snapshot - so it is best not to do any large installations or reconfigurations.